# Drawing Previous Multiple Days High and Low Lines

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to draw lines of last 30 days high and low.
I have captured the OHLC values in an array and able to retrieve the values also
I want to extend those lines where the current day high is lesser than previous multiple days highs and same thing for the low, where I want to extend the lines of the lows where current day low is greater than previous days lows

I want to stop extending the lines of those days whose high prices where the current day high price has gone above the previous period high line prices and same thing for low, where I want to stop extending the low lines where the current day low has gone lower than the previous low line price.

I am stuck on how to draw and extend and stop extending these lines even though I have captured the information in array.

Any help is appreciated.

...

```
//@version=5
indicator("High-Low Lines", overlay = true)
Ref_TF = input.timeframe('D', "Reference TF")
Lookback_period = 30     //input.int(30, 'LookBack Data')
getOHLC_last_30(_period)=>
    array<float> opArr = array.new<float>(_period+1)
    array<float> hiArr = array.new<float>(_period+1)
    array<float> loArr = array.new<float>(_period+1)
    array<float> clArr = array.new<float>(_period+1)
    array<int> bar_idx_Arr = array.new<int>(_period+1)  // capture the bar index of that past day
    for i = 0 to _period
        opArr.set(i, open[i])
        hiArr.set(i, high[i])
        loArr.set(i, low[i])
        clArr.set(i, close[i])
        bar_idx_Arr.set(i, bar_index[i])
    [opArr, hiArr, loArr, clArr, bar_idx_Arr]


[OpenArray,HighArray,LowArray,CloseArray, Bar_IndexArray] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, Ref_TF, getOHLC_last_30(Lookback_period), lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)


show_pdhl = input(true, 'Show Previous Day High/Low')
show_highs = input(true, 'Show Previous Highs')
show_lows = input(false, "Show Previous Lows")

//////Lines//////////

bars = +100
n = 1

var line[] arr_high_line = array.new_line()   // declare an empty array to store our lines in , 
var line[] arr_low_line = array.new_line()    // declare an empty array to store our lines in 

// Function to add same line type to an array at a given level
addLine(arr, y, clr) =>
    // array.unshift(arr, line.new(bar_index, y, bar_index + bars, y, style = line.style_dotted, extend=extend.none, color=clr, width = 1))
    array.unshift(arr, line.new(bar_index - bars, y, bar_index, y, style = line.style_dotted, extend=extend.none, color=clr, width = 1))

// Function to loop line array extending right 
extend(arr, len) =>
    for l in arr                 
        line.set_x2(l, len)

// Function to end lines on current bar if significant point breaks line price
// m is used as a multiplier to inverse the bool condition allowing the same function to be used to check for highs or lows 
// a multiplier of 1 is used for highs and -1 for lows to take the inverse of the condition 
// We run the loop backwards to avoid indexing errors when removing elements 
// we remove the line from the array after setting the x2 at the current bar so that we do not continue to extend it to the right 
endLine(arr, m) =>
    p = m > 0 ? high : low // check high or low depending on inverse or not 
    if array.size(arr) > 0
        for i  = array.size(arr)-1 to 0
            l  = array.get(arr, i) 
            lp = line.get_price(l, bar_index)
            if p * m > lp * m // check price against line price. multiply by 1 or -1 for inverse operation 
                line.set_x2(l, bar_index)
                array.remove(arr, i)



for i = 1 to Lookback_period
    _from = Bar_IndexArray.get(i)
    p_high = HighArray.get(i)
    p_low = LowArray.get(i)
    if show_highs //and close < p_high
        addLine(arr_high_line, p_high, color.red)
    if show_lows //and close > p_low
        addLine(arr_low_line, p_high, color.green)


// check highs against Previous Days high
// check lows against Previous Days lows 
// set line at current bar if broken 
// remove from arrays 
endLine(arr_high_line, 1)
endLine(arr_low_line, -1)

// // extend lines in both arrays to the right
// extend(arr_high_line, bar_index + bars)
// extend(arr_low_line,  bar_index + bars)
```

...